# How to change range in formula for multiple rows when using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am summing cells in a sheet as follows and storing them in column `AH`

```
=SUM(C2:AG2)
```

I am doing this for multiple rows like `C3:AG3`, `C4:AG4` and so on upto `C51:AG51` and storing them in the respective AH row number such as `AH3`, `AH4` and so on.

I want to import the values in column `AH` into another sheet. For this I am using the following formula

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "sheet name!AH2")
```

Now I want to apply the above formula for other rows like AH3, AH4 and so on.

The problem is there are hundreds of values like this and it becomes tedious to this manually.

Is there any way to automatically update the formula for multiple rows?

Thanks

EDIT1

[image]

From the above image, I want the value for AH2 in the B2, AH3 in B3, and so on.

Currently I have to do this manually by editing the formula in each cell. How do I do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "sheet name!AH2:AH51")
```

OR for full range of Column AH

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "sheet name!AH2:AH")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, using your answer I can import the values from AH2:AH51 in a single cell in the other sheet. But I want the values to be imported to multiple cells in the other sheet

Comment: if you importrange lets say 10 cells from source sheet, target sheet output will be distributed in 10 cells as well, not single cell.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so simple and I was stuck in this for a while now.